# Tiling images with PHP GD

Tags: php, image, gd, tiling

I'm trying to tile multiple images, i.e. put one directly underneath another. They all have the same width (120px) and differing heights.

This is what I have:

```
$finalbg = null;
for($i=0; $i<7; $i++) {
    $addbg = imagecreatefromjpeg('images/left/'.$url[$drawn]);
    $addsize = imagesy($addbg);

    if($finalbg != null) $basesize = imagesy($finalbg); else $basesize = 0;
    $newsize = $addsize+$basesize;

    $newbg = imagecreatetruecolor(120, $newsize);
    if($finalbg != null) imagecopy($newbg, $finalbg, 0, 0, 0, 0, 120, $basesize);
    imagecopy($newbg, $addbg, 0, $basesize, 0, 0, 120, $addsize);
    $finalbg = $newbg;
}

header( "Content-type: image/jpeg" );
imagejpeg($finalbg);
```

The sizes are outputting correctly, but it keeps telling the image contains errors, and I have no idea why :( Same thing if I try to output addbg or newbg.

Thanks.

Comment: Is $url[$drawn] correct? Or do you need something like $url[$i]?

Comment: to see the actual error that you are getting, go to File>Save Page As then open the "image" up in notepad. Read the error, and post it here.

Comment: yup, $url[$drawn] is correct :)

I see a load of random characters, but no error message.

Comment: I added 
    if($finalbg != null) imagedestroy($finalbg); 
    $finalbg = $newbg;    
    imagedestroy($newbg);
    imagedestroy($addbg);

in the loop, and 
    imagedestroy($finalbg);
after the loop. Unless I comment the one for $newbg, I get the error:
Warning: imagesy(): 11 is not a valid Image resource in... (lines containing finalbg)

I'm at a total loss here...

Comment: Even simply    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
   $addbg = imagecreatefromjpeg('images/left/'.$url_mo[0]);
   imagejpeg($addbg);
   imagedestroy($addbg); doesnt work ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, apparently the problem was that there was HTML on the page that was supposed to be rendered, which turns out not to be possible in combination with a GD image.

So I took a different approach. I saved the rendered image as a file, like so:

```
imagejpeg($finalbg, 'images/left/bg.jpg');
```

and set it as the background in CSS. And now it works!